# java spring web application does not work after deployment on server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, deployment

I have developed my first web-application using spring hibernate. The application works fine when i run it on local tomcat server. but when i deployed it on external tomcat server, it does not work. it throws the following exception.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)


java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/pretech/ErrorController : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.pretech.ErrorController)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2948)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1208)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
```

thanks.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java version on server is too old - upgrade it or compile your project with a lower source level.

See:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/pretech/ErrorController : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Comment: thnx geoff. java version on server was 1.6 i downgraded my java from 1.7 to 1.6 now it works. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have compiled the Jave source code with `JDK 7` and you are running it on `JRE 6` or any prior version. You need to recompile the source code with appropriate version compatible with JRE version

```
major version number of the class file format being used.
J2SE 8 = 52 (0x34 hex),
J2SE 7 = 51 (0x33 hex),
J2SE 6.0 = 50 (0x32 hex),
J2SE 5.0 = 49 (0x31 hex),
JDK 1.4 = 48 (0x30 hex),
JDK 1.3 = 47 (0x2F hex),
JDK 1.2 = 46 (0x2E hex),
JDK 1.1 = 45 (0x2D hex)
```

Hope this clarifies!